# Most pythonic way to combine filters on dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

Let's say I have a dataframe of integers between -100 and 100 on which I would like to apply two filters: value greater than 0, absolute value greater than 50. For now I apply these filters that i combined by multiplying them, as so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-100,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

greater_than_0 = (df>0).astype(int)
abs_greater_than_50 = (abs(df)>50).astype(int)
greater_than_50 = greater_than_0.multiply(abs_greater_than_50)

display(greater_than_50.head())
display(df*greater_than_50)
```

Another solution would be to use the following method:

```
greater_than_0 = np.where(df>0,1,0)
abs_greater_than_50 = np.where(abs(df)>50,1,0)
greater_than_50 = pd.DataFrame(data=greater_than_0*abs_greater_than_50, columns=df.columns)

display(greater_than_50.head())
display(df*greater_than_50)
```

I was wondering wath would be the best solution, knowing that I have hundreds of thousands of rows and hundreds of columns. Any totally different approach would be much appreciated if I have missed something!

(I know that the filter 'value greater than 50' would do the job using only one filter, it is just for the sake of an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `&` to combine the boolean dataframes

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-100,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
cond = (df > 0) & (df.abs() > 50)
filtered_df = df[cond]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [pandas.DataFrame.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html). please look at example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-100,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

greater_than_0 = (df>0).astype(int)
abs_greater_than_50 = (abs(df)>50).astype(int)
greater_than_50 = greater_than_0.multiply(abs_greater_than_50)
test1 = df*greater_than_50

greater_than_0 = (df>0)
abs_greater_than_50 = (abs(df)>50)
test2 = df.where(greater_than_0 & abs_greater_than_50, 0)

pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(test1, test2)
```